# Import got stuck at 99 for 2 days in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I started import  2 days ago. It got stuck at 99%. When I verified in `impdp`, 
it is at below stage since 2 days. It didn't even move forward and it is still in executing state when I verified in database by issuing

```
select* from dba_datapump_jobs;

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_AND_BITMAP/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_AND_BITMAP/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
```

All answers are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be due to a number of issues. Is there anything in the alert log? Does the log file for this import list any errors? Have you checked to confirm that enough tablespace has been allocated to the schema(s) in question? What is the current state of the job? What is the current state of the workers? Is this a RAC database, and is the import being run in parallel?

Comment: There were no errors found in alert log,,all tablespaces are good and Import is till running ,looks like it stucks at same phase as i mentioned in above question.it is stand alone server.
orker 1 Status:
  State: EXECUTING
  Object Type: SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
  Worker Parallelism: 1

Worker 2 Status:
  State: WORK WAITING

Worker 3 Status:
  State: WORK WAITING

Worker 4 Status:
  State: WORK WAITING

Worker 5 Status:
  State: WORK WAITING

Worker 6 Status:
  State: WORK WAITING

Comment: How is the HD/filesystem? Is there ample space for your tablespaces to be autoextended? Oracle can't necessarily tell when the filesystem is full, so it's possible that the disk is full, even if your tablespaces aren't showing as being full. Please check this page for more info: https://community.oracle.com/blogs/dearDBA/2015/07/22/impdp-stalls-for-no-apparent-reason

If everything looks ok and you're still not able to determine a cause, I would suggest trying the import again with different criteria. E.G. since your job keeps getting caught on them, try using EXCLUDE=STATISTICS

Comment: @solllodolllo - It works perfectly.Thanks fro your help:)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there are any deadlocks on the objects being used

Comment: I didn't find any dead locks